# How to save selected columns in memory?

Tags: angular, angular-material

There is a Columns component that allows to choose which column to display in the table and which not.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Columns</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="activeCols" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let c of allCols" [value]="c">{{ c }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

How to prevent the previously selected columns for a table from being reset when refreshing the page?

Project on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zf8cft-tuah4g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to save your data. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zf8cft-eezhy6?file=app/app.component.ts).
More info is here  [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), this way you'll be able to retain the data after refresh

> The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage
>   object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across
>   browser sessions. localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except
>   that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data
>   stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends —
>   that is, when the page is closed.
>
> It should be noted that data stored in either localStorage or
>   sessionStorage is specific to the protocol of the page.
>
> The keys and the values are always strings (note that, as with
>   objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

Here is an example for how to save data to Local Storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("myActiveColumns", activeCols);
```